# What is the maximum replication factor for a partition of kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, partitioning, kafka-topic

I hava kafka cluster having 3 brokers and a couple of topics with each having 5 partitions. Now i want to set the replication factor for the partitions.

What is the maximum replication factor which i can set for a partition of kafka topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Replication factor** determines the number of replications each partition have, this allows Kafka to automatically failover to these replicas
> when a server in the cluster fails so that messages remain available
> in case of failures

Partition replicas are distributed across brokers and one broker should keep one replica that means we can't have more replicas than the number of brokers

***Max Replication factor <= brokers number.***

This is also meant to determine **min.insync.replicas**, that means it will always be less than or equal to replication-factor

***min.insync.replicas means <= Replication factor***

> **min.insync.replicas** is the minimum number of copies of the data that you are willing to be online at any time to continue running
> and accepting new incoming messages.

**Ideally replication factor 3** is good as mentioned above, however, based on the use case you can tune replication factor less than 2 (means high risk) and the same time more than 3 provide better availability but more overhead and more size required.

**While deciding replication factor consider below points as well:**

**A): Broker Size** Replication factor directly impacts the overall broker disk size

So a high replication factor requires more disk size

B)**Large Number of Partition replication:** In case of a large number of partitions replication extra latency is added.

Answer (score 3):

A broker can only host a single replica for a partition.

So if your cluster has 3 brokers, the maximum replication factor you can have is 3.

While it's in theory possible to setup a topic with a very large replication factor, in practice there's rarely any benefits setting it above 4. Replicas are used to high availability and durability and basically determine how many brokers you can go offline before losing any data. If you have 3 replicas, it's unlikely all 3 brokers will crash/fail at the same time.